# Free Alternative to AutoCAD Map

Tags: open-source-gis, autocad, autocad-map, free-software

I would like to know if there are any free (for commercial use) software packages that roughly correlate to the functionality in AutoCAD Map.  Specifically, I am looking for something that is:

- Commandline based.
- Opens .dwg and possibly .dgn files.
- Can generate world files for raster
  georeferencing.
- Optional: Civil 3d functionality such
  as alignment and profile generation.

Comment: +1 - Thanks for posting this question.  It saved me the trouble of doing so myself and/or having to search online, read reviews ----------->  Cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Draftsight**
http://www.3ds.com/products/draftsight/draftsight-overview/

or even better

**DoubleCAD**
http://www.doublecad.com/Products/DoubleCADXTv3/tabid/1100/Default.aspx

Comment: That's great!  I had no idea about doublecad.

Comment: Thanks!  I have been evaluating both of those, and I have found that Draftsight runs smoothly and can open more of my large files.

Comment: Glad to help and you got the result you wanted

Comment: Another project, http://sourceforge.net/projects/librecad/ derivated from QCAD

Comment: @Mapperz Why do you prefer DoubleCad over Draftsight?

Comment: Bezier curves and the more powerful, Advanced polyline editing.

Comment: There is Free Personal option for DoubleCad while you can only use DraftSight demo for free.

Answer (score 2):

You should try Kosmo http://www.opengis.es/ it reads DXF/DWG (version 2000 only) and DGN you can georeference rasters and has some CAD functionalities profile generation can be done with Sextante it is shipped with Kosmo. It is open source

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look in GvSIG (OADE version), it starts to have good build-in tools for CAD, so :

- it has a command line tools to edit every points (with some topology functions)
- it opens .dwg, .dxf and .dgn files
- it generates world files for raster georeferencing
- it integrates like Kosmo, Sextante and now Grass for the OADE version so you can make profile

GvSIG exists in two flavour and both are opensource : [original](http://www.gvsig.org/web/) and [OADE](http://oadigital.net/software/gvsigoade) (derivated from original and with some extra features)

Regarding the others tools I discover with Mapperz link, you will just have to use GvSIG + a true CAD tool.

Do you choice :)

Comment: Thanks, Thomas, I didn't realize that GvSIG had all of those features.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good plugin
**QAD for QGIS**

https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qad/

which can be a good alternative to AutoCAD tools in the free version.

You have the command prompt and drawing tools.

[image]

There is additional information here

youtube.com/watch?v=EGf12BWYNDY&ab_channel=Q-tips

as well as the other CAD tools available, about which you can read & watch below

https://vertical-srl.it/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/50_best_QGIS_plugins_2016-amsantac.pdf

read AutoCAD section

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LaVaGGcgO0w&ab_channel=GeoRGB
QGIS CAD tools for editing